# Assembly Calculating location of variables

Tags: assembly, masm, x86-16, data-segment

```
MYDATA SEGMENT

ARRAY DD 30 DUP(?)
MESSAGE DB 'Hello World$'
BA DD MESSAGETWO

MYDATA ENDS


DATASECOND SEGMENT

HELLO DB 20 DUP(?)
MESSAGETWO 'I AM ASSEMBLY$'

DATASECOND ENDS
```

The Physical address of MYDATA is 19AC0h

What is the offset of `MESSAGE` ? what is the offset of `MESSAGETWO` ?

I don't know how to do it, do I just count the array (30) + count the letters in `MESSAGE` ? (11) = 41 ?

And what about `MESSAGETWO` ? Does it matter it is not the same segment?

Thank you!

Comment: Please tag this MASM and/or x86-16 if that's what you're asking about.

Comment: @PeterCordes I will sir.

Comment: It should be pretty much how you say it is.  I am not super familiar with MASM and it could be that that assembler adds some implicit padding or something, so I don't feel confident writing an answer.  But I do think you have the right idea.  But do note that since the array is an array of dwords, each entry is 4 bytes long.  Same for `BA`.

Comment: @fuz Thank you! The thing is, I need to find the offset not its address so is the information about the physical address of MYDATA segment is redundant ? because offset is just how 'deep' things inside the segment, no? and also about the Dword array- does it mean ARRAY DD 30 takes up 30*4 bytes? thank you!

Comment: @StackOMeow I can't tell you about your first question.  And yes, if each element of the array occupies 4 bytes, then the whole array occupies 120 bytes.